# Replace characters in all tables in Database Postgres

Tags: sql, replace, character

I'm using PostgreSQL with pgadmin.
I need to replace multiple characters in all fields of type string, and in all tables in my database.

Comment: Welcome on stack, please read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq, and try to create a question with additional informations instead of a statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below with caution - adjust as necessary, and make sure you review each and every resultant query (yes - this generates a resultset of queries) before copying the results and executing - as this may include queries that would attempt to modify views, calculated fields, system tables etc. etc.

I'm a T-SQL'er - but I believe the below should be valid in PostgresSQL.

```
SELECT 'UPDATE ' || TABLE_SCHEMA || '.' || TABLE_NAME ||
       ' SET ' || COLUMN_NAME || ' = REPLACE(' || 
       COLUMN_NAME || ', ''FROM'', ''TO'')'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE DATA_TYPE LIKE '%char%'
```

For additional information, which may provide ideas on how to adjust this query, check out [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-columns.html).

Comment: You may want to exclude the information schema tables themselves

Comment: @Bohemian - +1.  Indeed - and various other bits 'n' bobs - I'm not a hardcore Postgreser (?!) - the query is intended to be a starting point, there'll be a lot to gain from reviewing the output rather than blindly executing!

Answer (score 1):

This will list all columns that are "character" type in your database:

```
SELECT t.tablename, a.attname AS column_name
FROM pg_attribute a
JOIN pg_class c ON a.attrelid = c.oid
JOIN pg_tables t ON t.tablename = c.relname
JOIN pg_type on pg_type.oid = a.atttypid
WHERE t.schemaname not in ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog')
and pg_type.typname in ('varchar', 'text', 'char')
order by 1,2;
```

Then you must go through and do the updates.

Comment: thank you very much.
But as I do?
I have no experience with sql